# Excel VBA macro to remove formulas for a dynamic range not working

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2013

I have a range of four cells.  The furthest left cell (column A) is a unique value.  The next three cells to the right are populated with formulas.  Columns B and C are Vlookups that pull values from sheet 2 when column A is populated (otherwise the cells have a value of "").  Column D populates with the current date when a value is put into Column A (otherwise the cells have a value of "" as well).

What I'm trying to do is run a macro when a unique value is put into column A that will kill the formulas in B,C,D and keep their values.  Then it automatically selects the cell in the subsequent row in column A.  A3 is fixed which is why I used the `End(xlDown)` method and then `Activecell.Offset`.

This is what I have that is bombing Excel when it runs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Value = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Value
  Range("A3").Select
  Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Always turn off event handling before changing a value in a Worksheet_Change. If you don't, the routine will try to run on top of itself.
2. If a change in column A is what dictates the need to remove formulas then restrict the processing to when there is a change in column A.
3. ActiveCell is not a good choice here. Use Target instead. Target may be one or more than one cell.
4. Look for the first empty cell in column A from the bottom up, not the top down.
5. Use error control to ensure that the VLOOKUPs have returned values, not errors.

Here is some general code that should get you started.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns("A"))
            If Not IsError(rng.Offset(0, 1)) Then
                rng.Resize(1, 3) = rng.Resize(1, 3).Value
            End If
        Next rng
        With Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            'optionally put in new VLOOKUP formulas in column B and C
            '.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1, Sheet2!C1:C3, 2, FALSE)"
            '.Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1, Sheet2!C1:C3, 3, FALSE)"
            .Select
        End With
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this worked perfectly.  The only change I had to make was `rng.Resize(1, 4) = rng.Resize(1, 4).value`.  And thank you!!!